# Strange invalid syntax Error in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a piece of code that looks completely fine,

```
def _change_id(self, model, path, it,(old_id, new_id)):
```

But whenever I try to run it in my terminal python returns, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: I tested in Python 2.7.x shell and it worked. Python 3.x does throw an error. For those that see this question, the error indicator points at `(old_id, new_id)` parameter

Answer (score 4):

The use of the tuple parameter was removed in python 3.0. This caused more issues than it was worth.  You can rewrite it this way:

```
def fun(p1, b_c, p2):
    b, c = b_c
```

the parameter `b_c` was a tuple:

```
fun(1, (1, 2), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its called Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking (only in python3)

see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, tupple parameter unpacking was removed in python 3 as per this link [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Edit: @Yoav and @jonrsharpe beat me to it